# Why is my map not displaying properly on mobile

Tags: javascript, css, ios, google-maps

The web app is working properly on computer, but when we try to access the maps through mobile sometimes we get the map, other times  we just get the address selection
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7IG42h6OCcxR2kzNm9YRFcwMTExTl92alA0Y0VYOVh2UDVv/view?usp=sharing
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7IG42h6OCcxdGFXeHpEZ3ptZnNtVFlEUGtwSGc1aW9MZnI4/view?usp=sharing

I can'r figure out if I am missing some code on my js for mobile, but everything works fine

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var panelDiv = $("<div class='container'>");
    panelDiv.attr("id", "floating-panel");
    var st = $("<strong>Start:</strong>");
    var s = $("<select id='start'>");
    var b = $("<br>");
    var en = $("<strong>End:</strong>");
    var e = $("<select id='end'>");
    panelDiv.append(st);
    panelDiv.append(s);
    panelDiv.append(b);
    panelDiv.append(en);
    panelDiv.append(e);
    var mapDiv = $("<div id='map'>");
    var rightDiv = $("<div id='right-panel'>");
    $(".container").after(rightDiv);
    $(".container").after(mapDiv);
    $(".container").after(panelDiv);
    //your code here
    //easy way "<option value="addres">TEXT</option>"
    var startAdd = [
        {
            address: "",
            text: "Select Lot"
        },
        {
            address: "ucla los angeles, ca ",
            text: "UCLA"
        },
        {
            address: "100 Universal City Plaza, Universal City, CA 91608",
            text: "Studio City"
        },
        {
            address: "200 Santa Monica Pier, Santa Monica, CA 90401",
            text: "Santa Monica"
        },
        {
            address: "6925 Hollywood Blvd, Hollywood, CA 90028",
            text: "Hollywood"
        },
        {
            address: "3835 Cross Creek Rd, Malibu, CA 90265",
            text: "Malibu"
        },
        {
            address: "231 S Grevillea Ave, Inglewood, CA 90301",
            text: "Inglewood"
        },
        {
            address: "7850 Melrose Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90046",
            text: "Fairfax"
        }
    ];

    function createOptions() {
        $("#start").empty();
        //create array to hold start <option> tags
        var newOptions = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < startAdd.length; i++) {
            var newOption = $('<option>');
            newOption.attr("value", startAdd[i].address); // add [i] here to index element
            newOption.text(startAdd[i].text); // add [i] here to index element
            newOptions.push(newOption); // add new option to the array
        }
        //appending=expensive, keep array of elements and then use .html to add array to <select>
        $("#start").html(newOptions); // once loop is complete, add the array of elements to the DOM

    }
    createOptions();

    //for end selection
    function createEndOptions() {
        $("#end").empty();
        //create array to hold start <option> tags
        var newOptions = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < startAdd.length; i++) {
            var newOption = $('<option>');
            newOption.attr("value", startAdd[i].address); // add [i] here to index element
            newOption.text(startAdd[i].text); // add [i] here to index element
            newOptions.push(newOption); // add new option to the array
        }
        //appending=expensive, keep array of elements and then use .html to add array to <select>
        $("#end").html(newOptions); // once loop is complete, add the array of elements to the DOM

    }
    createEndOptions();

});

function initMap() {
    //used for directions output
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    //will display map image on <div id="map">
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 9,
        //LA
        center: { lat: 34.052235, lng: -118.2437 },
        //remove buttons on map
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    //direction set on this element
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

    var onChangeHandler = function () {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    // [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.
    //fixed violation by making onChangeHandler { passive: true }
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler, { passive: true });
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler, { passive: true });
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    directionsService.route({
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING'
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Check the css on your map, try defining a `height` and `width`, also `position: relative`.
Looking at your code, you are placing the <div id="map"> in document ready, not sure if that is a good idea.  Google Map needs to know the space it will take up on the page so it can determine the images to send

Comment: my css for map :
#map {
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 70%;
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 85%;
  max-width: inherit;
}

Comment: so do you recommend leaving the div on html instead on js, or just place it before document ready?

Comment: Yes, keep the <div id="map"> inside the html.  Maybe try using a number for height not a percent.

Comment: Have any of the recommendations work?

Comment: @wnordmann, yes you were correct! It needed to place my tags directly on html for google maps to load properly. Thank you !!!